# Azure DiagnosticsMonitorTraceListener not working

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-diagnostics

Azure is starting to do my nut, I am trying to get diagnostics tracing working and have followed various guides (all pretty much say the same thing). I now can't debug locally (I get errors) and RDP doesn't seem to want to connect. I have the following in the web config:

```
 <system.diagnostics>
<trace>
  <listeners>
    <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="AzureDiagnostics">
      <filter type="" />
    </add>
  </listeners>
</trace>
```

And then this in the webrole.cs:

```
public override bool OnStart()
    {
        var diagnostics = DiagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultInitialConfiguration();

        diagnostics.Logs.ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter = LogLevel.Undefined;
        diagnostics.Logs.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        diagnostics.Logs.BufferQuotaInMB = 10;

        CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
            RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString"));

        DiagnosticMonitor.Start(account, diagnostics);

        return base.OnStart();
    }
```

And this in the service definition file:

```
<Imports>
  <Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />
  <Import moduleName="RemoteAccess" />
</Imports>
```

And this in the service config file:

```
<ConfigurationSettings>
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<snip>;AccountKey=<snip>" />
```

I don't get any errors when the site is deployed, I tried a text listener locally which worked fine but I get nothing in table storage on Azure. This has worked before but I have since moved the deployment to another subscription and storage account. Because of my RDP problems, I can't even see if various files are created locally on the instance and I don't know what files to check for anyway!

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally managed to get it working by following this guide: [Here](http://blog.elastacloud.com/2011/01/31/migrating-to-azure-diagnostics-with-sdk-v1-3/)

Basically the only difference was in the OnStart method of my web role and rather than the code above which is found in almost all of the examples online, I had to use the following, perhaps because I am using multiple instances?

```
public override bool OnStart()
    {
        string wadConnectionString = "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString";
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue(wadConnectionString));

        RoleInstanceDiagnosticManager roleInstanceDiagnosticManager = storageAccount.CreateRoleInstanceDiagnosticManager(RoleEnvironment.DeploymentId, RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Role.Name, RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Id);
        DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration config = DiagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultInitialConfiguration();

        config.Logs.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1D);
        config.Logs.ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter = LogLevel.Undefined;

        roleInstanceDiagnosticManager.SetCurrentConfiguration(config);
        return base.OnStart();
    }
```

Thank you elastacloud!

Comment: Thank you. I was going insane. You should mark your own answer as the correct one, you really helped me out.

Comment: For subsequent visitors to this answer, note that `OnStart` is no longer necessary. Logging is initialized automatically based on your Windows Azure Profile setting. This is as of SDK 2.2, I think.